# Some of databases I had created in the server not displaying in my device in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

Some of databases I had created in the server not displaying in my device in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but any another device can I tried to delete and reinstall the SQL Server management studio with no changes, and their is no filters active, I can find it if I select the available databases to the master and use the query `SELECT * FROM sys.databases` , but I can't see it in the Object Explorer, also when I create a new database the new database appears then when I refresh the server it's disappear, but I can still find it in any another device, it's hosted in the cloud and the provider is Microsoft Azure, Thanks a lot
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you run the query `SELECT [name] FROM master.sys.databases` do you see the *missing* database in the list of names?

Comment: Are you using the same account to connect to the database server?

Comment: @Glorfindel ,Yes I'm using the same account, and when I create a new database the new database appears then when I refresh the server it's disappear, but I can find it in another device

Comment: @J.D. I can find it if I select the available databases to the master and use the query ` SELECT * FROM sys.databases ` , but I can't see it in the Object Explorer

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your post of what the results of that query show? Is this SQL Server instance hosted in the cloud and if so, which provider?

Comment: @J.D. I added in the question the image you asked for ,  and thank you very much  <3,

Comment: @J.D. Yes it's hosted in the cloud and the provider is Microsoft Azure

Comment: This is a strange issue I have to say. I'm wondering if it could be related to [contained users / databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-ver16) somehow, but I'm not sure. I'm not super familiar with that feature. What happens if you open a new query window in SSMS and just run this query: `USE [YourDatabaseNameThatIsMissing];`

Comment: @J.D. I used the   `USE [YourDatabaseNameThatIsMissing];` command and work successfully but the database still not shown in the object Explorer, as shown in the image provided.

Comment: Interesting, so in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you can query a table from the *missing* database then too, I assume? If so, sounds like SSMS could be messed up and you should re-install the latest version or try the latest version of Azure Data Studio.

Comment: @J.D. I all ready remove and reinstall the latest version, but I will try the Azure Data Studio, thank you a lot for helping me I appreciate it. <3